# How to edit large XML files in PHP based on a record in the XML Node

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to modify a 130mb+ XML file via PHP so it only shows the results where a child node is a specific value. I'm trying to filter this because of limitations via the software we're using to import the XML into our website.

**Example: (mockup data)**

```
<Items>
<Item>
  <Barcode>...</Barcode>
  <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
  <Title>...</Title>
  <Content>...</Content>
  <ShowOnWebsite>false</BrandDescr>
</Item> 
<Item>
  <Barcode>...</Barcode>
  <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
  <Title>...</Title>
  <Content>...</Content>
  <ShowOnWebsite>true</BrandDescr>
</Item> 
<Item>
  <Barcode>...</Barcode>
  <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
  <Title>...</Title>
  <Content>...</Content>
  <ShowOnWebsite>false</BrandDescr>
</Item>
</Items>
```

**Desired result:**
I want to create a new XML file with only the records where the child "ShowOnWebsite" is true.

**Problems I've run into**
Because the XML is so large simple solutions like using SimpleXML or loading the XML into the body and editing the nodes in there don't work. Because they all read the entire file into memory which is too slow and usually fails.

I've also looked at prewk/xml-string-streamer (https://github.com/prewk/xml-string-streamer) which is great for streaming large XML files because it doesn't place them in memory, although I can't find any way to modify the XML via that solution. (Other online posts say you need to have the nodes in memory to edit them).

Anyone got an idea on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Goal

> Desired result: I want to create a new XML file with only the records where the child "ShowOnWebsite" is true.

### Given

#### test.xml

```xml
<Items>
<Item>
  <Barcode>...</Barcode>
  <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
  <Title>...</Title>
  <Content>...</Content>
  <ShowOnWebsite>false</ShowOnWebsite>
</Item> 
<Item>
  <Barcode>...</Barcode>
  <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
  <Title>...</Title>
  <Content>...</Content>
  <ShowOnWebsite>true</ShowOnWebsite>
</Item> 
<Item>
  <Barcode>...</Barcode>
  <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
  <Title>...</Title>
  <Content>...</Content>
  <ShowOnWebsite>false</ShowOnWebsite>
</Item>
</Items>
```

### Code

This is the implementation I wrote. The `getItems` yields the childs without loading the xml at once into the memory.

```php
function getItems($fileName) {
    if ($file = fopen($fileName, "r")) {
        $buffer = "";
        $active = false;
        while(!feof($file)) {
            $line = fgets($file);
            $line = trim(str_replace(["\r", "\n"], "", $line));
            if($line == "<Item>") {
                $buffer .= $line;
                $active = true;
            } elseif($line == "</Item>") {
                $buffer .= $line;
                $active = false;
                yield new SimpleXMLElement($buffer);
                $buffer = "";
            } elseif($active == true) {
                $buffer .= $line;
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
    }   
}

$output = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Items></Items>');
foreach(getItems("test.xml") as $element)
{
    if($element->ShowOnWebsite == "true") {
        $item = $output->addChild('Item');
        $item->addChild('Barcode', (string) $element->Barcode);
        $item->addChild('BrandCode', (string) $element->BrandCode);
        $item->addChild('Title', (string) $element->Title);
        $item->addChild('Content', (string) $element->Content);
        $item->addChild('ShowOnWebsite', $element->ShowOnWebsite);
    }
}

$fileName = __DIR__ . "/test_" . rand(100, 999999) . ".xml";
$output->asXML($fileName);
```

### Output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items><Item><Barcode>...</Barcode><BrandCode>...</BrandCode><Title>...</Title><Content>...</Content><ShowOnWebsite>true</ShowOnWebsite></Item></Items>
```

Answer (score 0):

`XMLReader` has an `expand()` method, but `XMLWriter` is missing the counterpart. So I added a `XMLWriter::collapse()` method in [FluentDOM](https://thomas.weinert.info/FluentDOM/).

This allows to read the XML with XMLReader, expand it to DOM, use DOM methods to filter/manipulate the it and write it back with XMLWriter:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the target writer and add the root element
$writer = new \FluentDOM\XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri('php://stdout');
$writer->setIndent(2);
$writer->startDocument();
$writer->startElement('Items');

// load the source into a reader
$reader = new \FluentDOM\XMLReader();
$reader->open(getXMLAsURI());

// iterate the Item elements - the iterator expands them into a DOM node
foreach (new FluentDOM\XMLReader\SiblingIterator($reader, 'Item') as $item) {
  /** @var \FluentDOM\DOM\Element $item */
  // only "ShowOnWebsite = true"
  if ($item('ShowOnWebsite = "true"')) {
    // write expanded node to the output
    $writer->collapse($item);
  }
}

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();

function getXMLAsURI() {
  $xml = <<<'XML'
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Barcode>...</Barcode>
    <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
    <Title>...</Title>
    <Content>...</Content>
    <ShowOnWebsite>false</ShowOnWebsite>
  </Item> 
  <Item>
    <Barcode>...</Barcode>
    <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
    <Title>...</Title>
    <Content>...</Content>
    <ShowOnWebsite>true</ShowOnWebsite>
  </Item> 
  <Item>
    <Barcode>...</Barcode>
    <BrandCode>...</BrandCode>
    <Title>...</Title>
    <Content>...</Content>
    <ShowOnWebsite>false</ShowOnWebsite>
  </Item>
</Items>
XML;
  return 'data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($xml);
}
```